# Is it ok to create all control variables as field variables and then set their references once together in Android

Tags: android, performance, out-of-memory

I have written an app which is crashing perennially on one particular device the moment an intent is loaded.

So what I'm assuming the cause of crash is this. I need some expert guidance if I'm true before I embark upon changing the whole structure of the app.

I create all the control variables that are needed in the intent together as field variables. Then in OnCreate() method I call a method setReference() that initialises all the control variables with references. The app in question has more than 200 control variables and I'm creating references to atleast 200 of them in OnCreate().

I'm assuming that this is creating a lot of load on memory allocation and is the cause of crash.
Here is the code (First I create all control variables as field variables):

```
ImageButton ibRep, ibRep2, ibEmail, ibShare;
EditText eName, ed_Sa, ed_Ann, ed_prm, ed_mat, ed_pr_age, ed_asa, ed_asa1, ed_cirsa, ed_term, ed_la, ed_trsa, t_ppt;
EditText ed_age, i_ed_age;
Spinner sp_ttl, spOpt189, spPlans_List, sp_ann_pmt_mode, sp_834_opt, sp_term, sp_ppt, sMode;
LinearLayout llsur_ben, llPlan_List, ll_Mat, ll_Trm, ll_ann, ll_output, ll_bas_input, ll_calc_ch,
        ll_sa_b_fab, ll_xtra_ben, ll, ll_temp1, ll_temp2;
TextView hdMoney_Back, tvSur_ben1, tvSur_ben2, tvSur_ben3, tvSur_ben4, tvSur_ben5,tvSur_ben6, tv_disclaimer;
TextView tvSur_ben_amt1, tvSur_ben_amt2, tvSur_ben_amt3, tvSur_ben_amt4, tvSur_ben_amt5, tv_term, tv_defper;
TextView tvPrm_Hdr, tv_hd_mat, tv_ermsg1, tv_ermsg2, tv_ermsg3, tv_ermsg4, tv_pr_age, tv_ext_ben, tv_tpp,
        tv_maturity, tv_spp_amt, tv_la_amt, tv_sa_amt, tv_mat_sa_per, tv_sa_per_amt, tv_bonus, tv_fab,
        tv_sa, tv_sa1, tv_mat_sa, /*tv_ydab, tv_hdab, tv_qdab, tv_mdab,*/ tv_age_op, tv_term_op, tv_ppt, tv_ch_amt,
        tv_pl_sel, tv_ann_op, tv_ann_pr, tv_y_ann, tv_h_ann, tv_q_ann, tv_m_ann, tv_y_gp, tv_hy_gp, tv_q_gp,
        tv_m_gp, tv_d_gp, tv_ytx1, tv_htx1, tv_qtx1, tv_mtx1, tv_dtx1, tv_ytx2, tv_htx2, tv_qtx2, tv_mtx2,
        tv_dtx2, tv_ytot1, tv_htot1, tv_qtot1, tv_mtot1, tv_dtot1, tv_ytot2, tv_htot2, tv_qtot2, tv_mtot2,
        tv_dtot2, tv_ytpp, tv_htpp, tv_qtpp, tv_mtpp, /*tv422,*/ tv42, tv_tax1, tv_crrep, tv_crrep2, tv_xrisk_cover,
        tv_mb_title, tv_mat_disclaimer, tv_prm_disclaimer, tv_ch_repval, tv_834_opt, tv_mode, tv_send_msg;

TableRow trPlan_List, trAnnOpt, trAnOptHd, tr834Opt, tr834Opt_Hd, tr_acc_sa, tr_trsa, tr_pwb, tr_tax2,
        tr_netprm2, tr_la, tr_ret_at_mat, tr_spp, tr_la1, tr_sa, tr_mathd,tr_mathd1,tr_mathd2,tr_mathd3,
        tr_tax1, tr_acc_sa1, tr_cir, tr_gender, tr_sprm;
RadioButton rd_prm, rd_mat, rd_ann, rd_sa, rd_male, rd_female;
CheckBox chk_addb, chk_tr, chk_pwb, chk_addb_845, chk_ab_845, chk_cir;
Button btn_calc, btn_rep;
ImageButton btn_recalc, btn_recalc1, btn_ch_repval, btn_send_msg;
ScrollView sv1;
ProgressDialog pd;
ProgressBar pb;
```

Then I call the setReference() method in onCreate() method:

```
 public void setReference() {
    try {
        sv1 = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sv);
        hsv_repInput = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hsvReportInput);

        ibRep = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnReport);
        ibRep2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnReport2);

        sp_ttl = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spTitle);
        spOpt189 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp189option);
        spPlans_List = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPlansList);
        sp_ann_pmt_mode = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spAnnuityPmtMode);
        sp_834_opt = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp834option);
        sp_term = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spTerm);
        sp_ppt = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spPPT);
        sMode = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spMode);

        llsur_ben = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llSurBen);
        llPlan_List = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llPlanList);
        ll_Mat = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llMaturity);
        ll_Trm = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llTerm);
        ll_ann = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llAnn);
        ll_output = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llOutput);
        ll_bas_input = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llBasicInput);
        ll_calc_ch = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llCalcChoice);
        ll_sa_b_fab = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llsabfab);
        ll_xtra_ben = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.llExtraBenefit);
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_prem_calculator);
        ll_temp1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lltemp1);
        ll_temp2 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lltemp2);

        hdMoney_Back = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hdMoneyBack);
        tvSur_ben1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sb1);
        tvSur_ben2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sb2);
        tvSur_ben3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sb3);
        tvSur_ben4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sb4);
        tvSur_ben5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sb5);
        tvSur_ben6 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sb6);
        tvSur_ben_amt1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sba1);
        tvSur_ben_amt2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sba2);
        tvSur_ben_amt3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sba3);
        tvSur_ben_amt4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sba4);
        tvSur_ben_amt5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sba5);
        tvPrm_Hdr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPremiumHeader);
        tv_hd_mat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hdMaturity);
        tv_mode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMode);
        tv_ermsg1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvErrMsg1);
        tv_ermsg2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvErrMsg2);
        tv_ermsg3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvErrMsg3);
        tv_ermsg4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvErrMsg4);
        tv_pr_age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrAge);
        tv_ext_ben = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvExBen);
        tv_disclaimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisclaimer);
        tv_term = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTerm);
        tv_defper = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDefper);
        tv_maturity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvRetAtMAt);
        tv_spp_amt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSppAmt);
        tv_la_amt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLaAmt);
        tv_sa_amt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSaAmt);
        tv_mat_sa_per = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.matSaPer);
        tv_sa_per_amt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsaPer);
        tv_bonus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBonus);
        tv_fab = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvFab);
        tv_sa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvsa);
        tv_sa1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSa1);
        tv_mat_sa = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.matSa);

        tv_age_op = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAgeOp);
        tv_term_op = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTermOp);
        tv_ppt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPPT);
        tv_ch_amt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvChoiceAmt);
        tv_pl_sel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPlanSelected);
        tv_tax1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTax1);

        tv_ann_op = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tAnnOption);
        tv_ann_pr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tannPrem);
        tv_y_ann = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tYlyAnn);
        tv_h_ann  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tHlyAnn);
        tv_q_ann = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tQlyAnn);
        tv_m_ann = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tMlyAnn);
        tv_y_gp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ygp);
        tv_hy_gp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hygp);
        tv_q_gp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qgp);
        tv_m_gp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mgp);
        tv_d_gp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dgp);
        tv_ytx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ytx1);
        tv_htx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hytx1);
        tv_qtx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qtx1);
        tv_mtx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mtx1);
        tv_dtx1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dtx1);
        tv_ytx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ytx2);
        tv_htx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hytx2);
        tv_qtx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qtx2);
        tv_mtx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mtx2);
        tv_dtx2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dtx2);

        tv_ytot1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ytot1);
        tv_htot1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hytot1);
        tv_qtot1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qtot1);
        tv_mtot1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mtot1);
        tv_dtot1 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dtot1);

        tv_ytot2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ytot2);
        tv_htot2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hytot2);
        tv_qtot2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.qtot2);
        tv_mtot2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mtot2);
        tv_dtot2 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.dtot2);
        tv_ytpp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yTotPremPaid);
        tv_htpp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hyTotPremPaid);
        tv_qtpp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.qTotPremPaid);
        tv_mtpp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTotPremPaid);

        tv42 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.t42);
        tv_tpp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvtpp);
        tv_xrisk_cover = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvExtraRiskCover);
        tv_mb_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMoneyBackTitle);
        tv_mat_disclaimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMatDisclaimer);
        tv_prm_disclaimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPrmDisclaimer);
        tv_ch_repval = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtChRepValues);
        tv_834_opt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv834Option);
        tv_send_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSendMessage);

        btn_ch_repval =(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnChRepValues);
        btn_send_msg = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnSendMessage);

        trPlan_List = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trPlanList);
        trAnnOpt = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trAnnOption);
        trAnOptHd = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trAnnOptHd);
        tr834Opt = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tr834Option);
        tr834Opt_Hd = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tr834OptHd);
        tr_acc_sa = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trAccSA);
        tr_acc_sa1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trAccSA1);
        tr_trsa = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trTRSA);
        tr_pwb = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trpwb);
        tr_cir = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trCirSa);
        tr_tax1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trTax1);
        tr_tax2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trTax2);
        tr_netprm2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trNetPrem2);
        tr_la = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trLA);
        tr_ret_at_mat = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trRetAtMat);
        tr_spp = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trSpp);
        tr_sa = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trSa);
        tr_la1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trla1);
        tr_mathd = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trMathd);
        tr_mathd1 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trMatHd1);
        tr_mathd2 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trMatHd2);
        tr_mathd3 = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trMathd3);
        tr_gender = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.trGender);

        t_ppt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tPPT);
        ed_Sa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtSA);
        ed_Ann = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAnnuity);
        ed_prm = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPremium);
        ed_mat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtMaturity);
        eName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
        ed_pr_age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPra);
        ed_asa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtASA);
        ed_term = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTerm);
        ed_la = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edLA);
        ed_trsa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTRSA);
        ed_asa1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtASA1);
        ed_cirsa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtCir);
        ed_annuity_premium = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAnnuityPremium);

        rd_prm = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdPremium);
        rd_mat = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdMaturity);
        rd_ann = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdAnnuity);
        rd_sa = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdSA);
        rd_male = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdMale);
        rd_female = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.rdFemale);

        chk_addb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkADDB);
        chk_tr = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkTR);
        chk_pwb = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkpwb);
        chk_cir = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkCir);
        chk_ab_845 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkAB_845);
        chk_addb_845 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.chkADDB_845);

        btn_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalc);
        btn_recalc = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRecalc);
        btn_recalc1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnRecalc1);
        tv_crrep = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCreateReport);
        tv_crrep2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtCreateReport2);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "15 sr: "+ e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And ofcourse all the variables are not used all the time but are getting created, referenced and thus may be occupying too much space . May be this was an ok practice when the app is small and not dependent on so many control variables.

Am I thinking right that it is a wrong practice which is leading to its crash on some devices.

In case it is then should I be creating control variables in each method and set references in individual methods itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should not be a problem. You are just storing the reference of objects which are already created.

But using a lot of views in a single activity might be problematic.